# Update listview in a tab upon spinner selection

Tags: android, listview, android-spinner

I have two tabs where in the first tab has a list view and the second tab displays a map. I have a spinner where in you selected the city. Based on the spinner selection, the listview should display values for that current city. My spinner is my main activity where I have declared the tabhost. The list view is in a different activity and my tab host calls this activity.

How do I refresh my listview as soon as a value is selected from the spinner.

```
        MovieAdapter adapter = new
      MovieAdapter(currentContext, R.layout.activity_list_view__deals, result);
      listview.setAdapter(adapter); adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
      listview.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

How do i pass the currentContext of the listview activity when I selected the value from the spinner from a different activity?

Comment: You don't need upate ListView if its not visible to user. It doesnt make sence for me. Just when listview is about to show, update it with current data.

Comment: Listview is the default tab . Thats why I need to update it as soon as my spinner value is selected